# responsetext to receive multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have set up post xmlhttprequest and it work working great.  I however would like to set up the responseText to receive multiple variable in an array, comma delimited or whatever.

This is how I am currently scooping up my return php echo command.

```
var return_data = hrequest.responseText;
```

Maybe something like this?

```
var update = new Array();

if(response.indexOf('|$|' != -1)) {
  update = response.split('|$|');

  alert(update[0]);
  document.getElementById("button1").value=update[1];
  document.getElementById("button2").value=update[2];
}
```

Comment: return json and you can have any kind of complex object you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be easier to send data as JSON from php.

Send JSON from php:

```
echo json_encode( $array);
```

Parse to array from responseText:

```
var return_data_array = JSON.parse(hrequest.responseText);
```

Comment: So it should look something like this?
    $arr = array('button1' => $num1, 'button2' => $num2, 'value1' => $value);
    echo json_encode($arr);

Comment: and my responsetext 
var return_data_array = JSON.parse(hrequest.responseText);{
 var button1 = jsonObj[1].button1;
 var button2 = jsonObj[1].button2;
 var value1 = jsonObj[1].value1;
}

Comment: yes except you have extra `{}` wrapping code after the parse and wrong variable ..should be `var button1=return_data_array.button1`

Comment: use `console.log( return_data_array)` to inspect array in browser console, or `console.log("button 1=", return_data_array.button1)`

Comment: one thing to know... JSON.parse not available in older browsers but can include library `json2.js` for those browsers. Easy to find in google or github